# Term for using someone or something else as cover or concealment

Tags: terminology

Best example, rider swinging down the side of their horse to use it [the horse] as concealment or cover viewed from the other side of the horse.

Other examples: thieves using a political protest or riot for premeditated looting; tailgating one's way past a door (i.e. using someone else's authorization); slipping unrelated funding or statute into a bill.

Update: Thanks for all the suggestions.

I'm looking for a word that describes the class of actions, not words describing the action itself. Like "ingratiating behavior" vs.  "sucking up"

Comment: You already used the right word: *cover.* Cf. 'under cover of' on ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/under-cover-of

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[stalking horse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stalking-horse)*

> A false pretext concealing someone’s real intentions. [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Also *Trojan horse*

> A person or thing intended secretly to undermine or bring about the downfall of an enemy or opponent:
>   *the rebels may use this peace accord as a Trojan horse to try and take over* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

And *[red herring](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/red-herring)*

> Something, especially a clue, that is or is intended to be misleading or distracting:
>   *the book is fast-paced, exciting, and full of red herrings* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

More mundane terms might be

> - [pretense](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pretense): An attempt to make something that is not the case appear true:
>     *his anger is masked by a pretense that all is well*
> - [pretext](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pretext): A reason given in justification of a course of action that is not the real reason:
>     *the rebels had the perfect pretext for making their move*
> - [guise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/guise): An external form, appearance, or manner of presentation, typically concealing the true nature of something:
>     *he visited in the guise of an inspector*

[all *Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Answer (score -1):

Such a tactic might also be called a *diversion, distraction* or *subterfuge.*